# algorithm to convert md5 (or maybe another hashing method?) to integer where it is possible to set possible resulting integer ranges (eg: 1-10000)?

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, md5, range

the topic pretty much describes what we would like to accomplish.

a) start with a possible range of integers, for example, 1 to 10000.

b) take any md5 hash, run it thru this algo.

c) result that pops out will be an integer between 1 to 10000.

we are open to using another hashing method too.

the flow would ideally look like this:

```
string -> md5(string) -> algo(md5(string),range) -> resulting integer within range
```

is something like this possible?

final note: the range will always start with 1.

if you have an answer, feel free to post just the general idea, or if you so desire, php snippet works too :)

thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure but it seems as if this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283631/one-to-one-integer-mapping-function ?

Comment: Or hmm, you only want to convert a hash to an integer within a specific range?

Comment: If you're hashing into a 10K range, then cryptographic hashing is overkill.  The practical guarantee it gives (no collisions) is completely destroyed by the small range.  You'd be better off using a faster hash that maintains a reasonable spread.  crc32 is one that has several command line and library implementations.

Comment: yep, we ended up using crc32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since MD5 (and SHA-1, etc.) will give you 128 bits of data (in PHP, you'll get it in hexadecimal string notation, so you need to convert it to an integer first). That number modulo 10000 will give you your integer.

Note however that many different hashes will convert to the same integer; this is unavoidable with *any* sort of conversion to your integer range, as the `modulo` operation essentially maps a larger set of numbers (in this case, 128 bits, that is numbers from 0 to 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,456) to a smaller set of numbers (less than 17 bits, numbers from 1 to 100,000).

Comment: the more unique the better but some overlap is a-ok. will look into this and get back.

Comment: MD5 doesn't generate hex digits - common implementations just format it that way by default.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Okay, it gives you a 128-bit integer back, usually formatted in hexadecimal. Edited, is it better now? :)

Comment: @Piskvor Actually, it gives you 8 bytes of data; interpreting it as an integer is just one option. :)

Comment: @Nick Johnson: Can we agree on 128 bits of data, then?

Answer (score 0):

since the range that we want will always start at 1, the following works great. all credit goes to Piskvor, as he was the one who provided the basic idea of how to go at this.

the code below seams to accomplish what we want. please chime in if this can be (not the code, its just for reference, but if the idea) improved at all. running the code below will result in 6305 / 10000 unique results. that in our case is good enough.

```
<?

$final=array();

$range=10000;

for($i=1;$i<=$range;$i++){

    $string='this is my test string - attempt #'.$i;

    echo 'initial string: '.$string.PHP_EOL;

    $crc32=crc32($string);

    echo 'crc32 of string: '.$crc32.PHP_EOL;

    $postalgo=$crc32%$range;

    echo 'post algo: '.$postalgo.PHP_EOL;

    if(!in_array($postalgo,$final)){
            $final[]=$postalgo;
    }

}

echo 'unique results for '.($i-1).' attempts: '.count($final).PHP_EOL;

?>
```

enjoy!

Comment: just ran it thru 100000 attempts, it resulted in 63070 uniques. out of curisity, anyone want to chime in regarding why 6305 for 10000, 63070 for 100000?

Comment: That's not the count of _unique_ values. You calculated that 3695 values do not occur. With 10,000 pigeons and 6305 holes, at least some holes have more than one pigeon, at least some values are not unique. Use `final[$postalgo]++` and `for all i if (final[i]==1) count++` to count unique.

Comment: i meant that 6305 of the 10000 values will occur, you are correct. that's what we are most important to us. and yes, i know / understand how to calculate the duplicates.