# converting hash value(md5, sha1 etc..) to integer in a fixed range

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, md5

Lets say I have an hash function md5 and I hash some string and it gives me the some value and I need to convert it into an integer value with a fixed range.

As given here for `crc32()` [algorithm to convert md5 (or maybe another hashing method?) to integer where it is possible to set possible resulting integer ranges (eg: 1-10000)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305297/algorithm-to-convert-md5-or-maybe-another-hashing-method-to-integer-where-it)

For example lets say:

```
$value=md5("dog");
echo $value;

Output: "06d80eb0c50b49a509b49f2424e8c805"`
```

Now I need to convert this value into integer so that I can use it in a look-up table of size 1000. Thus when I convert it the size of this hash value should be between 0 to 999. How can I do that?

Comment: This is going to be a lookup table with a lot of overlap, so you might as well use modulo / the division remainder (`$crc % 1000`).

Comment: if i make a large look-up table say 100million entries for that crc32() is not a good option, although you are correct but for large amount of data i need to use md5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base_convert to change the hexadecimal output from md5 into decimal, and then use the bcmod function to convert that down to a number in your chosen range:

```
<?php
$valuetohash = "dog";
$range = 1000;
$hashslot = bcmod(base_convert(md5($valuetohash), 16, 10), $range);
echo $hashslot;
```

Output: 26

Changing "dog" to "parrot" produces 800, changing it to "cat" produces 260 (*which, amusingly, shows that cats are 10 times better than dogs*).

Note, if you are using a different hash that doesn't map to "a big hex number", eg crc32 maps to an integer, you will need to do the above differently (in the case of crc32, you can just straight %mod it to the range for example, as per the original comment on your question).