# Encrypt a 32-bit integer to 32-bit integer and then decrypt it

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One-to-one integer mapping function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283631/one-to-one-integer-mapping-function)

I need to encrypt a 32-bit integer to a 32-bit integer and also i can decrypt it,

Dose any one know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!!

Thanks, Yes, i don't need high secure, and encrypt 32-bit **unsigned integer** to 32-bit **signed integer**.

Comment: I'll know I'll regret asking, but  what are you doing with this encrypted 32bit int?

Comment: @MitchWheat: I was thinking the same. I don't see any value in trying to "encrypt" from int -> int. Most encryption schemes inherently increase the information entropy of whatever they're encrypting by increasing the output size. It's not a hard rule, but generally increasing entropy is a good thing for encryption.

Comment: @Mike: I believe one can increase the entropy in many cases without increasing the size as well.

Comment: The [(Shannon) entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) is literally just the number of bits. A 32-bit integer will have 32 bits of entropy (assuming a uniform distribution, which seems to be a fair assumption for this question).

Answer (score 2):

- Pick a random integer as encryption key.
- XOR the integer with the key to encrypt.
- XOR the integer with the key again to decrypt.

Comment: With this scheme you must not reuse a key.

Comment: Thanks very much, Yes, i don't need high secure, and encrypt 32-bit unsigned integer to 32-bit signed integer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to get a modern level of security with something that starts and ends so small.

Classically, one can XOR with a particular secret number. XORing with this number again will result in the original number.

However, this would fall to a known-plaintext attack in a fraction of a second. You could even break it in such a case with pencil and paper quickly enough. It may also not remove certain properties you'd like to remove (like being able to guess "nearby" id numbers from one you can see).

Comment: Thanks, Yes, i don't need high secure, just encrypt 32-bit unsigned integer to 32-bit signed integer

Comment: I wouldn't even call this encryption, since the way to break it has been known for centuries (King Louis XIV's cryptographer could manage an even more secure variant on this that had previously been considered unbreakable), but it could serve to obfuscate in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a random permutation of all 32 bit integers, and use that to encrypt. Calculate the inverse permutation to decrypt.

This would have the best possible security, but requires to store the entire permutation (128 GB key size). =)

Comment: Or use a parameterized function to do so.  The random permutation is one of such possible function and the 125GB permutation table would be the parameter. It should be possible to find a more complex function with a smaller parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Following is very naive, but works: mix some bits and then XOR (^) with some number.

The naivety of such approach concerned with Shannon's concept of entropy - you cannot get good encryption without increasing of result message length

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use RSA encryption on the integer. This is not necessarily more secure,  because the numbers to work with are so small. Here is a working example:

```
// computes b^x mod m, so that the intermediate calculations are not truncated by uint.
private ulong powmod_ulong(uint b, uint x, uint m)
{
    if (x == 0) return 1;
    ulong tmp = powmod_ulong(b, x / 2, m);
    return x%2 == 1 ? (((tmp*tmp)%m)*b)%m : (tmp*tmp)%m;
}

private uint powmod(uint b, uint x, uint m)
{
    return (uint) powmod_ulong(b, x, m);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    uint p = 62989;
    uint q = 61967;
    uint n = p * q;                // 3903239363
    uint phiN = (p - 1) * (q - 1); // 3903114408
    uint e = 900548521;            // chosen to be coprime to phiN
    uint d = 3163940785;           // = -739173623 = multiplicative inverse of e. e * d mod phiN == 1.

    uint plain = 12345;
    uint encrypted = powmod(plain, e, n);
    uint decrypted = this.powmod(encrypted, d, n);
}
```